# Flask Deploy on Heroku - Error R10

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, flask

I successfully deployed the app and ran the url its shows application error.
Checked the Log, it states:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Procfile

```
web: python run.py ${PORT}
```

run.py

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=False)
```

I also tried with

```
 from os import environ
 from app import app
 app.run(debug=False, port=environ.get("PORT", 5000), processes=2)
```

In both the case the error still persist

views.py

```
 @app.route('/')
 @app.route('/login', methods=["GET","POST"])
 def login():
 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really not how you run a Flask application in production. You need an actual server, such as gunicorn, and you point that to your `app` object:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

This is all fully explained in the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python-o).